# Referencing parameters in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to set up a pipeline that is triggered by an initial pipeline and pass some values from the triggering pipeline to the second one.

I'm using the 'build job' option to call the second pipeline, which works fine to trigger the pipeline, however I can't seem to properly reference the parameters that I am passing in the second pipeline.

I'm calling the second pipeline and passing parameters like so:

```
script{
                build job: 'Docker-Pipeline', paramters: [string(name: 'source_branch', value: String.valueOf(BRANCH_NAME))]
                
            }
```

And have the parameters defined in the second pipeline:

```
parameters {
      string(name: 'source_branch', defaultValue: "", description: 'set by triggering pipeline')
    }
```

However I can't figure out how to properly reference the parameter to use the value being passed. Trying to write it out returns nothing:

```
stage('PrintParameter'){
            steps{
                sh 'echo ${source_branch}'
            }
        }
```

Results in the following in the console output:

```
[Pipeline] { (hide)
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (PrintParameter)
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo


[Pipeline] }
```

Any advice one how to properly pass/define/reference the parameters would be very helpful. The jenkins documentation doesn't seem to cover this level of detail.

Answer (score 0):

For string interpolation to work you need to wrap the command with double quotes.

```
sh "echo ${source_branch}"
```